# Can not undo startup system-software of a Huawei quidway switch

Tags: switch, huawei

I follow this [article](http://labnario.com/too-small-flash-to-upload-a-new-software/):

In the `_hide`, I can not undo startup system-software:

```
[-LW-A]undo startup system-software
                         ^
Error:Unrecognized command found at '^' position.
```

the version is this:

```
[-LW-A]dis version
Huawei Versatile Routing Platform Software
VRP (R) Software, Version 5.30 (S2300 V100R003C00SPC301)
Copyright (C) 2008-2009 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Quidway S2352P-EI uptime is 513 days, 15 hours, 33 minutes

[Unit 0] EMFEA uptime is 513 days, 15 hours, 33 minutes
128M bytes DDR Memory
16M bytes FLASH
Pcb      Version : CX22EMFEA REV B
Basic  BOOTROM  Version :  209 Compiled at Nov  4 2009, 14:50:43
Software Version : VRP (R) Software, Version 5.30 (S2300 V100R003C00SPC301)
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The post you're linking to uses `delete`, not `undo` to delete the file.

Comment: hi, friend, I mean this command : `[S3328-hidecmd]undo startup system-software`